# Counting amount of lines in txt file java file io

Tags: java, io

```
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
    System.out.println(count);
    count = count + 1 ;
}
```

For example my text file has 1,000 lines, Each line having information on it. It seems to be counting all of the digits and not every line.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `inputStream` is a `Scanner` you need to consume the data from the `InputStream`

```
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
   inputStream.nextLine(); <-- add this
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop never ends because you don't consume the stream. An alternative using Java 8:

```
try (Stream<String> s = Files.lines(Paths.get(file), UTF_8)) {
  count = s.count();
}
```